# Установка шрифтов в более сложных элементах, чем text view

Tags: android, шрифты, material-design, android-xml

По тз необходимо поставить шрифты на табы и элементы `recyclerView` списка.

Шрифт: `Roboto-Bold`

Пошел в гугл гайдлайнс, скачал необходимые шрифты с форматом `.ttf` и закинул их в assets.

p.s. разметка или код здесь не особо важны, как я предполагаю.

Полез искать инфу, как этот шрифт установить - и во всех виденных мною примерах применялся простой `TextView`, все гайды твердят примерно следующее:

```
Open your main activity file and insert this into the onCreate() method:

TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Chantelli_Antiqua.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Относительно табов и списка подобного рода вещей попросту нет, к тому же они находятся во фрагментах.

По поводу установки этих шрифтов напрямую через xml так-же ничего не нашел.

Есть ли какие-то более новые способы для установки шрифтов под элементы `Material Design`, которых не нашел?

У `Material Design` виджетов я не нашел этого метода вовсе.

Как подойти к этой задаче?

Comment: через XML шрифт установить нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить таб из TabLayout можно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33272002/3212712):

```
mainTab = ((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(desiredPosition);
```

Подобным же образом найдите в нём TextView (скорее всего это он и есть) и назначьте ему шрифт.

Назначить шрифты для элементов RecyclerView ещё проще - у вас точно есть доступ к его адаптеру а в нём точно есть ссылка на все его TextView - в onBindViewHolder методе адаптера и применяйте шрифты

Аналогичным образом можно это сделать и для всех остальных виджетов.